# Как очистить форму после отправки? Или может быть я не правильно понял

Tags: php, yii2

Как очистить форму после отправки? Или может быть я не правильно понял
?

Я отправляю данные через форму, и перехожу на новую страницу. Если я её обновляю, то форма отправляется заново.

Обычно я применял

```
$hostname = Yii::$app->request->hostInfo;
            header("Location: ".$hostname."/basic/web/index.php?r=index/contact");
            exit();
```

И всё отлично работает. 
Но в этом случае мне не подходит ридирект, потому что нужно отобразить страницу.

```
public function actionContact()
{
    $model = new Contact();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

         unset($_POST);//Этот варинат не помогает
        unset($_POST['Contact']);//Этот варинат не помогает
        unset($_POST['textarea']);//Этот варинат не помогает
        $model->textarea = null; //Этот варинат не помогает
        //---------------------------------
        return $this->render('contact_yes'); //Мне нужна эта страница, потому ридеректить нельзя

    } else {
        return $this->render('contact', ['model' => $model]);
    }   
}
```

Если можно, мини-вопрос 2, почему это происходит?

Comment: Обновление страницы - это отправка запроса **аналогичного** предыдущему. Поэтому, если не использовать редирект, то ваша проблема не решается. Все параметры (url, данные формы и прочее) уже хранится в истории браузера и будут использованы при обновлении страницы не зависимо от вашего желания.

Comment: Начните сначала с изучения самого php... рано Вам еще...

Comment: Совет: пересмотрите логику отрисовки страницы. Почти наверняка вы можете отдавать ту же страницу по GET-запросу после редиректа.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Спасибо Вам за ответ. Аж не вериться что с этим никак нельзя борость. Прямо обидно стало.

Comment: @Urmuz Tagizade Спасибо. Так я изучаю его на протяжении всего времени пока я работаю на нём.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushe Верно. Но это я не хотел применять Это решение смахивает на костылёк, как мне кажется.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushe Может быть через js DOM элементы? Или делать очистку истории? Мм..? Прросто не вериться что нельзя никак добиться желаемого результата. Должен же быть выход.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushe Решение скорее всего есть, у меня страница с капчей отрабатывает на отлично. А тут капчи нету. Если понять тот механизм работы который задействован в капче. То ту логику можно перенести сюда. А там , капча как-то меняет переменную в форме. Капчу мы достаём из action в контроллёре. Она там постоянно меняется. Вообщем, выход есть. Просто его нужно найти.

Comment: @gilo1212, то, о чем вы говорите, делается с использованием AJAX. А вот с "классической" отправкой формы через POST вы ничего не сделаете. Хотя я допускаю, что я недостаточно компетентен в вопросах клиент-серверного взаимодействия. Возможно кто-то и знает решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Прикол в том, что я как-то сделал такое в прошлой своей работе, но как именно не могу понять  ппц...

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev ППЦ ... Так я там-же pjax использовал.  Всё получилось.